# MD5 checks for repeated files in folder?

Tags: c#, file, hash, directory, md5

Let's say I have a folder with five hundred pictures in it, and I want to check for repeats and delete them.

Here's the code I have right now:

```
using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
{
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
    {
        return md5.ComputeHash(stream);
    }
}
```

Would this be viable to spot repeated MD5s in a specific folder, provided I loop it accordingly?

Comment: What programming language is your code in? What operating system and file system do you have? In theory, you could have md5 collisions (two different files having the same md5); in that improbable case, you'll need to compare files byte by byte.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I completely forgot to mention that. I'm using Windows 7 and C#.

Comment: I would sort the files by size in their directory. Then, if two files have the same size, I would compare them byte by byte (no need to md5 them, and you'll need to compare bytes anyway for md5 collisions). BTW, you problem is probably I/O bound, not CPU bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating hashes in order to identify identical files is OK, in any programming language, on any OS. It is slow, though, because you read the whole file even if that is not necessary.

I would recommend several passes for finding duplicates:

1. get the size of all files
2. for all files of equal size: get the hash of the first, say, 1k bytes
3. for all files of equal size and equal hash of first 1k: get the hash of the entire file

There is a risk of hash collisions. You cannot avoid it with hash algorithms. As MD5 uses 128 bits, the risk is  1 : (1 << 128) (roughly 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000001) for two random files. Your chances of getting the jackpot in your national lottery four times in a row, using only one lottery ticket each week, are much better than getting a hash collision on a random pair of files.

Though the probability of a hash collision raises *somewhat*, if you compare the hash of many files. The mathematically interested and people implementing hash containers should look up the "birthday problem". Mere mortals trust MD5 hashes when they are not implementing cryptographic algorithms.

Comment: Thanks a whole lot. I'll be doing this instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
internal static class FileComparer
{
    public static void Compare(string directoryPath)
    {           
        if(!Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
        {
            return;
        }
        FileComparer.Compare(new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath));
    }
    private static void Compare(DirectoryInfo info)
    {           
        List<FileInfo> files = new List<FileInfo>(info.EnumerateFiles());
        foreach(FileInfo file in files)
        {
            if(file.Exists)
            {
                byte[] array = File.ReadAllBytes(file.FullName);
                foreach(FileInfo file2 in files)
                {                       
                    int length = array.Length;
                    byte[] array2 = File.ReadAllBytes(file2.FullName);
                    if(array2.Length == length)
                    {
                        bool flag = true;
                        for(int current = 0; current < length; current++)
                        {
                            if(array[current] != array2[current])
                            {
                                flag = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if(flag)
                        {
                            file2.Delete();
                        }                       
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```